# Django form not showing in template

Tags: html, css, django, templates

Why is the form not showing in the browser?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ structure.name }} - Details</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% if error_message %}
    <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
    {% endif %}

    <h3>Structure: {{ structure }}</h3>

    <h3>Ajouter enregistrement</h3>
    <form action="{% url 'Structure:addrecord' structure.id %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for structure in all_structures %}
        <input type="radio" id="record{{ forloop.counter }}" name="record" value="record.id">
        <label for="record{{ forloop.counter }}">
          Nom de l'enregistrement: {{ record.record_name }}
        </label>
      {% endfor %}
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I test this in my browser, and inspect it, it gives me a form of this size: 1340px * 0 px.
I even explicitly gave a style="height: 500px", but it still gives me an empty form.

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVidl.png)

Thanks for the help guys!

**Edit:**

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Structure, Record

def index(request):
    all_structures = Structure.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Structures/index.html', {'all_structures': all_structures})

def detail(request, structure_id):
    #structure = Structure.objects.get(pk=structure_id)
    structure = get_object_or_404(Structure, pk=structure_id)
    return render(request, 'Structures/details.html', {'structure': structure})

def addRecord(request, structure_id, record.name, record.type, record.pos, record.long):
    r = Record(structure='structure_id', name='record.name', type='record.type', pos='str(record.pos)', long='str(record.long)')
    r.save()
    return render(request, 'Structures/details.html', {'structure': structure})
```

Also, I do not quite understand this yet because I am using a video tutorial series by thenewboston's channel, the variables I am using in addRecord are not known, and I want to use them from the model. Here are the models and urls files as well:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Structure(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Type(models.Model):
    typename = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.typename

class Record(models.Model):
    structure = models.ForeignKey(Structure, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #each structure has many records, each per line
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
    pos = models.IntegerField()
    long = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'Structure'

urlpatterns = [
    # /structures/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    # /structures/id
    url(r'^(?P<structure_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),

    # /structures/addrecord
    url(r'^(?P<structure_id>[0-9]+)/addrecord/$', views.addRecord, name='addrecord'),
]
```

Comment: Show the view. What is `all_structures` and does it contain anything? Where is `record` coming from?

Comment: I added all the codes you need.

Comment: This isn't real code; your `addRecord` definition contains illegal syntax.

Comment: What do you mean not real code? and what illegal syntax?

Comment: btw the variables (record.name, record.type, record.pos, record.long) should be (record_name, record_type, record_pos, record_long). I already corrected them it's just that I gave u a slightly old code.

Comment: Look this can't be your real code. The index view that renders the index.html template does not supply any parameter for `structure`, yet your screenshot shows "Structure: structure1" in the h3. So that cannot be the view that you are actually using.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the value of **all_structures** that you are passing in context from views.

If it is empty or not passed, form fields won't be displayed as per your template code.

Try to print its value either in the console or in template. That's how to Debug.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is not empty, When I go to the index template I can see 2 structures.